# Language and text are not preserved if I refresh to save the language I used local storage, and for courtpart translation and react

Tags: reactjs, class, local-storage, translate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM5DI.png)-----
The text doesnot remain the same if i refresh the page

Comment: You should copy the block of code as part of the question, as image links will become invalid over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the initial state from the localStorage, you should call `counterpart.setLocale()` to update the locale.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { lang } = this.state;
  counterpart.setLocale(lang);
}
```